# i am having problem understanding the differences in [word] and ["word"] in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, cs50

```
teams = []
    # TODO: Read teams into memory from file
    with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file)
        for team in reader:
             team[rating] = int(team[rating])
             # It works if i put team["rating"] but why?
             teams.append(team)
```

i wanted to change the rating of teams from the file into integer from string. In a previous problem i didnt need to put the "" inside of the [] and i cant fogure out why.
the precious problem is

```
results = {}
    for subsequence in subsequences:
        results[subsequence] = longest_match(DNA_sequence, subsequence)

    # TODO: Check database for matching profiles
    # Check if the value in subsequence i.e. longest nucleotide for each person is equal to that of the result
    for person in database:
        match = 0
        for subsequence in subsequences:
            # The value of subsequence of person is stored as string so change it to integer.
            if int(person[subsequence]) == results[subsequence]:
                match += 1
```

Comment: `rating` is a variable, with any possible value.  `"rating"` is a literal string.  Both may be used as a dictionary key.

Comment: ^ provided `rating` is an immutable type

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this modification helps to clarify what is going on:

```
teams = []
with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for team in reader:
         key = "rating"  # choose a key
         team[key] = int(team[key])
         teams.append(team)
```

The line `key = "rating"` mimics what your second piece of code does: assign a value to the variable `key`. Accessing the dict with `team[key]` is in this case equivalent to `team['rating']`